# Booting from USB using a CM3+

Tags: usb, boot, boot-issues, compute-module-3

i would like to use an usb stick to boot from my CM3+, because i would like to test the eMMC with different file systems.

I edited `/boot/config.txt` adding `program_usb_boot_mode=1` but nothing changed. Anyone got an idea what I could try? Maybe I am missing some line in the `config.txt`.

I don't think it makes a difference but I am using an USB 3.0 Stick.

Thanks already for the help.

Comment: this helps? https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/computemodule/cm-emmc-flashing.md

Comment: hm, this is for booting the CM3+ using the eMMC. I want to leave the eMMC empty for now and boot from an additional USB-stick that i plug into the USB port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found some stuff with help of the raspberry pi forum:
Here is how i used a usb stick to boot from (currently only works with CM3L, i dont know why)

For anyone who wants to boot from USB themselves. Here is how i did it.

1. Flash SD/eMMC with Raspberry Pi OS
2. Start the Raspberry Pi and open command line and type: echo program_usb_boot_mode=1 | sudo tee -a /boot/config.txt
3. Check if OTP bit is set correctly with: vcgencmd otp_dump | grep 17:
   If output is 17:3020000a everything is ok, otherwise reboot and try again
4. Now flash an empty USB-Stick with Raspberry Pi OS and add the line
   Program_usb_boot_mode=1
   To the config.txt file
5. Don’t forget to delete the files on the eMMC or remove the SD-card
6. Connect the USB_OTGID Pin to GND (If you removed the R12 Resistor)
7. Plug in the USB-Stick and connect a micro-USB cable with enough Ampere to POWER IN